# Sharepoint 2013 REST api from desktop application - Authentication

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to consume SharePoint 2013 REST services from a Desktop application ( cross-platform, cross-os ). Application is basically a HTML page in application view.
Is there a simple way I can authenticate my calls using HTTP methods ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get authenticated and receive a digest via a REST call.

```html
 string url = "http://Your.SP.Site";
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true });
                client.BaseAddress = new System.Uri(url);
                string cmd = "_api/contextinfo";
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ContentType", "application/json");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ContentLength", "0");

                StringContent httpContent = new StringContent("");
                var response = client.PostAsync(cmd, httpContent).Result;
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    JsonObject val = JsonValue.Parse(content).GetObject();
                    JsonObject d = val.GetNamedObject("d");
                    JsonObject wi = d.GetNamedObject("GetContextWebInformation");
                    retVal = wi.GetNamedString("FormDigestValue");
                }
```

The above example shows how to retrieve the digest in C# with the HttpClient.  This string needs to be passed as a header to all of the other rest calls you make to carry forward the authentication.  You can create a credential by passing in a username and password if needed.

I have more examples here:

https://arcandotnet.wordpress.com/2015/04/01/sharepoint-2013-rest-services-using-c-and-the-httpclient-for-windows-store-apps/

You can do these calls in JavaScript as well and Microsoft has a lot of documentation on that.  There is also .NET library, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.DLL (CSOM) that simplifies this type of coding but you must have the library installed on the client.

Comment: Excuse my possible ignorance, but how does this work without including a username and password? Is UseDefaultCredentials somehow including them in a header?

Comment: The second line of code contains "UseDefaultCredentials = true", so they are.  This will only work for SharePoint installations configured to use Windows Authentication, of coarse but credentials can also be passed by creating a NetworkCredential.

Comment: I'm not using .NET so this is a little confusing. Where are they credentials injected from exactly? Are they in a certain format?

Comment: They are passed from the operating system and uses the current users credentials, in .NET even if you specified a credential it is just an [object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkcredential(v=vs.110).aspx) you set username and password parameters on and the pass to the HttpClient.  Depending on what language you are using you will need to find an example or ask here on StackExchange how to authenticate to SharePoint.  This example likely does not translate outside of .NET other than extracting the digest from the response.

Comment: I found this, it may work with Basic auth but I have not tried:
static string _FormatBasicAuth(string domain, string user, string password)
{
const string format0 = @”{0}\{1}”;
const string format1 = @”{0}:{1}”;
string userName = string.Format(format0, domain, user);
return Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(
               string.Format(format1, userName, password)));
}   
System.Net.Http.HttpClient _Client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
_Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
         new AuthenticationHeaderValue(“Basic”, _FormatBasicAuth(Domain, User, Password));

Comment: This solution works nicely when using a Website with an Application Pool Identity setup as a user with permissions in your SharePoint site. Kudos!